# Unbricking Lenovo Tab M10 (X606F)

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, lenovo

For the purpose of flashing custom ROM I flashed Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus (X606F) with Android 9 ROM. I used SP Flash Tool. Now the tablet won't power on. Pressing buttons does nothing. Can't invoke fastboot nor recovery mode.

Red LED indicating charging is the only thing the tablet is giving me now.
I've tried to restore the device using official Lenovo's Rescue Tool.
Process of restoring gets stuck on 40% and won't go on.

Hard reset (pressing and holding volume buttons + power button for few secs) isn't doing anything.

What else I can try ?

I've followed the steps outlined and I got
to the point where Windows doesn't recognize the tablet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I'm gonna write require a lot of patience and common sense to achieve.

**Plus You do this at your own risk**

You require a windows machine to do all this

Assuming [this](https://www.lenovo.com/in/en/tablets/android-tablets/lenovo-tab-series/Lenovo-TB-X606/p/ZZITZTATBDX) is your device, download [bypass tool](https://mega.nz/file/aSQVAAZD#FoQFVqGCDmHqZnX8yERVPzuiLFLjGT3XADMgkUsMjEI) on your computer first.

Now install Python 3 on it ( 3.9 or anything recent recommended)
( dont forget to add python to PATH while installing )

then pip install this module via CMD

`pip install pyusb pyserial json5`

Launch bypass tool named mtk_bypass_rev3.exe (turn off real time protection if it's getting detected as Virus)

Hold both volume buttons and connect your device to pc with a usb cable

proceed forward if output looks like [this](https://telegra.ph/file/6fdba8dc92ab1e8ccb87c.jpg)

Now follow [this](https://www.getdroidtips.com/stock-rom-lenovo-tb-x306f/) guide

Comment: Thank you for the steps. I've added edit to my question.